# What to do when 1GB Huge Pages on ubuntu 20.04 failed using `echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages`

Tags: ubuntu

I try to enable 1GB Huge Pages on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 using [echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx5Cj.png) with the root user account, but I can't write to `/sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages` using the root user account, because there's "No such file or directory" for hugepages-1048576kB on my Ubuntu Desktop 20.04: How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

... maybe too late, but nonetheless for occasional googlers: large/huge pages of 1 GByte can only be allocated at boot time (and are immutable later on, too), in contrast to x86_64's *default* huge page size of 2MiB which *can* be allocated/changed at runtime (with similar `echo XX > ...` commands).

Either

- you set the "default" huge page size to 1GiB (overriding the above 2MiB default huge page size), by specifying `default_hugepagesz=1G hugepages=XX` **or**
- you define 1GiB as "extra" huge page size using `hugepagesz=1G hugepages=XX`

on your kernel's cmdline (eg. via grub).

You can even decide to define two (or more) sets as
`hugepagesz=1G hugepages=XX hugepagesz=2M hugepages=YY`
ending up with `XX` pages à 1GiB each and `YY` pages à 2MiB each (for whatever use case this might be suitable).

All these "special regions" have to be *contiguous* in physical RAM, regardless of being allocated at boot time (plenty of un-fragmented RAM free), or later.

Personally, I prefer *fixed* amounts of `nr_hugepages` for better control anyway, either set at kernel's boot time or set early in the boot process with an early systemd service/startup script.

If you have a server running for quite some time, RAM tend to get fragmented and your `echo XX > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages` might fail, simply because the kernel cannot find a contiguous memory region large enough to fit your XX hugepages in.